# how to create Fixed Sidebar during Scrolling between Header and footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create Fixed Sidebar during Scrolling between Header &  footer,and right side content as movable [here is my demo one](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/bpNAb)

Comment: so your header, footer and sidebar will always be visible on screen and only right content will scroll?

Comment: yes kittycat...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You have to take care of `padding` of your `body` because it's `padding-top` has to be more then or euqal to the `height` of your `header` and `padding-left` has to be more then the `width` of your `sidebar`. so that your content doesn't overlap with these two.

```css
body{
    padding:60px 0 0 150px;
}
.header {
 background: GREEN;
 color: #fff;
 position:fixed;
 width:100%;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 height:60px;
 z-index:100;
}

.navbar-brand {
 padding: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
 width: 250px;
 height: 51px;
 
}

.navbar {
 margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
 color: #fff !important;
 padding-bottom: 12px;
}

.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
   /*  background-color:#3385ff !important; */
    color:#d83b01 !important;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color: white;
}
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
   padding: 0 0 60px;
  
  
}


.footer {
  background: green;
 color: #fff;
 height:70px;
 position: fixed;
 width:100%;
 padding-bottom: 100% auto;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
}

#custom-search-input{
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 1px #E4E4E4;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#custom-search-input input{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#custom-search-input button{
    margin: 2px 0 0 0;
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 0;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 0 8px 0 10px;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#custom-search-input button:hover{
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-left: solid 1px #ccc;
}

#custom-search-input .glyphicon-search{
    font-size: 23px;
}
.sidebar{
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  position:fixed;
  top:60px;
  left:0;
  width:130px;
  /* background-color: #f5f5f5; */
  background: #fafafa none repeat scroll 0 0;
 padding:10px 5px; 
 border:1px solid #DDDDDD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
 <header>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar  header" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/home">
                        MYDEMO
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li >
                           <a id="login-button" 
                               role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal" data-backdrop="static" data-controls-modal="login-modal" >  <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> </a>
                           
                        </li>
                       
                       
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
            
            <!-- /.container -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:10px">
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6" >
            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Buscar" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="sidebar">
                <section> 
                <div class="filter-field">
                    <legend>filters</legend>
                    <div class="checkbox" >
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 1</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 2</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter"  value="">Option 3</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 4</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 5</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 6</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter"  value="">Option 7</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 8</label><br>
        <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 9</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 10</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter"  value="">Option 11</label><br>
       <label><input type="checkbox" class="filter" value="">Option 12</label><br>
     </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <p>this is moveable content</p>
             <p>this is moveable content</p>
              <p>this is moveable content</p>
               <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
             <p>this is moveable content</p>
              <p>this is moveable content</p>
               <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
              <p>this is moveable content</p>
               <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
              <p>this is moveable content</p>
               <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
             <p>this is moveable content</p>
              <p>this is moveable content</p>
               <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
             <p>this is moveable content</p>
              <p>this is moveable content</p>
               <p>this is moveable content</p>
                <p>this is moveable content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div><!--wrap-->
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: your answer is correct ,but i want like his 
http://demo.techbrij.com/730/fix-sidebar-scrolling-jquery.php

Comment: @Venky559 the code is in the article you linked. Did you even read it?

Comment: for this your code has to be altered more then you expect. which is not worth the time for anyone else but you.